# Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 ... brigtness become low befor 10 seconds inactivity

Tags: gnome, brightness, 17.04

I have just installed Ubuntu Gnome'7.04 on my Think Pad Yoga X1. Gnome is good after some customization. So Unity's death is not the end ))))) Everything is ok now but one strange thing. After 10-12 seconds inactivity display brightness getting about 50% lower. When i touch the touchpad or press any button it becomes high again. I checked all settings, i checked even bios settings. I reinstalled OS several times. I even tried another notebook (really it was ThinkPad too but different model). The same problem. I used Ubuntu 16.04 (unity) for long time and never had such issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Power settings panel, like so...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But ofcourse i've checked this settings many times. )))

Comment: @fyarik Then flip the switch to ON, and then back to OFF. If that fixes the problem, please remember to accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thank You for helping. I tried to do this for many times..... no results. Any other ideas?